# How to fix uneven sink bowl

Tags: sink, porcelain

We have a sink and cabinet we like, but the sink has two spots, one on either side of the drain, where the porcelein has formed a bowl and collects water. So after the sink has "emptied" there are two little puddles of water, one on either side of the drain. They start to smell and stain the bowl. Is there any way to fill or level these divots in the sink bowl?

Comment: Porcelain is hard to fix if not impossible. You could try using a resurfacing kit such as https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rust-Oleum-Specialty-1-qt-White-Tub-and-Tile-Refinishing-Kit-7860519/202246270 but it will never look perfect.

Comment: I would apply Rain-X to the sink, which should reduce the amount of water that collects. Might also try building it up with several layers of clear nail polish; it can always be removed later.

Comment: Is the sink now out of level front to back?

Comment: If it's **not** a problem with the installation of the sink (i.e. @JimStewart's question about front to back level) then you can ether hit it with a sledgehammer and replace it, or remove it, *then* hit it with a sledgehammer (or drop it on a hard surface) and replace it. Porcelain is either right when it comes out of the kiln, or wrong forever.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. The sink is level, the bowl surface just has these two pits that collect water. I am thinking the post-removal sledgehammer solution will be the most satisfying but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious for this product. I will look into the resurfacing kit as it seems like a possibility.

Comment: If you posted a picture we might be able to help you.